# Which accessory is more effective at increasing the success of Half Inch?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

I have got the Utility Belt (+25 deftness), the Honour Among Thieves (+3 defense), and the Medal of Freedom (+100 Deftness).  Which of these accessories would help my thief's Half Inch be most successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found:

- +25 Deftness: Utility Belt
- Doubles steal chance: Honour Among Thieves
- +100 Deftness: Medal of Freedom

### Because it doubles the steal chance, **Honour Among Thieves** increases Half Inch's success the most.

The percentage of success for Half Inch is:

```
[(deftness - 51)/237 + 2] * dropRate
```

Where deftness is the character's deftness, and dropRate is the dropRate of monster's item.

For a character with 0 deftness, Medal of Freedom results in a success rate of **2.21** * dropRate.  For the same character, Honour Among Thieves results in a success rate of **3.57** * dropRate.

Additionally: The percentage of success for the Thief's Theory scroll is `(Drop Rate * Character Level / 100)`.  So keep it on your highest leveled character.

## Sources:

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/937281-dragon-quest-ix-sentinels-of-the-starry-skies/57376411?page=2
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/937281-dragon-quest-ix-sentinels-of-the-starry-skies/55667688
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/937281-dragon-quest-ix-sentinels-of-the-starry-skies/56060501/619100631
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/937281-dragon-quest-ix-sentinels-of-the-starry-skies/56006395

Answer (score 0):

The Medal of Freedom.  The highest increase of deftness will lead to the better chances of Half Inch being successful.

Comment: Can you provide any supporting information for this?  Is there a formula for theft success?